# What does "push" mean in evaluation of Chrome DevTools-Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I evaluate one specific variable in *Chrome DevTools - Console*, this is the result:

```
(3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), push: ƒ]
```

---

I know the f means, the array contains a function.

What does the word **push** stand for in this context?

Comment: It's the name of the function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that someone has added a custom property to the array. It's not the standard `Array.prototype.push`, it's something else.

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
arr.push = () => 'some custom implementation';
console.log(arr);
```

[image]

If the standard `.push` was there, it wouldn't be showing up in the console.

(Try to avoid this in professional code. It's weird.)